# Private APT repository not upgrading

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am involved in developing a product based on Linux which was to be utilizing APT as an auto-update system.

I've created 3 versions of the package in .deb format. They have the same package name with the version numbers 0.0.0, 0.0.1 and 0.0.2. They were put in `/var/www/html/debian` on a server.

I created the repository itself with the command `rm debian/Packages.gz; dpkg-scanpackages -m debian /dev/null | gzip -9c > debian/Packages.gz`. The `rm` is to clear any previous version of the packages file.

On the machine I'm testing with, I've added the line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and have demonstrated that I can install the package with an `apt-get install` command.

Unfortunately - the upgrade doesn't seem to be working. If I include a new version of the deb (with the next logical version number) and do the `dpkg-scanpackages`, after an `apt-get update` I am able to `apt-get install` the new version of the package, but `apt-get upgrade` results in the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The version of Linux being used on the client device in Bananian - a debian based ARM distribution.

Is there any reason why `apt-get upgrade` would fail, without even expressly holding the upgrade back? How can I get my expected behaviour?

Comment: Does Packages have all three versions listed at once, or just the latest version? Are you just making the Packages file or the rest of the repo using something like mkdebidx?
I don't know why what you are doing is failing, but reprepro is not that much work and handles upgrades.

Comment: Yeah - Packages has all three versions listed at once (with the -m parameter). The debs have been made with dpkg -b, with dpkg-scanpackages making the Packages file. I'll give reprepro a try.

Comment: What if you just include the latest version in Packages. Another thing that can block apt-get upgrade is a dependency change. That requires apt-get dist-upgrade.